# Macro to change style of images and inlineshapes in word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Im working on a document generation tool that is run out of an excel workbook and was running into problems when generating a table of contents within the document. I am running a find and insert/replace macro to insert all of the information needed into the document. However When inserting images under certain text tags that have already been styled so the docuemnt understands how to build the table of contents, the images then take on the same style.

Because of this when generating the table of contents based off of text styles my images then get pulled into the table of contents destroying the format of the document.

My question is is there a way to change the paragraph style of images or inlineShapes in word through VBA Macros? I have tried

```
Dim img As Object 'Word.Shape
    Set img = wDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\1. SOW Templates\ Client Summary import.jpg")
    'img.ClearFormatting
    img.ConvertToInlineShape
```

and many other variants of the statement however i still cannot seem to find the proper command in the documentation.  Is this something that can be done within the realm of VBA or should i start working on a workaround?

Im learning new things about word and VBA everyday so if you have any input,tips, or additional resourses that will help me along the way please do not hesitate to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styles are applied to paragraphs, not shapes. So you need to apply the appropriate style to the paragraph that you insert the image into.

An excellent resource for learning about Word is [Shauna Kelly’s website.](https://shaunakelly.com/)

Another, with rather old but still valuable information, is the home of the [Word MVP’s](https://wordmvp.com/)

Comment: Ok thank you for the information, this is new to me! I will definitely check out those resources and see what i can learn. I guess i will just have to write a workaround to delete the images inside the table of contents after the fact.

Comment: @DakotaNyborg - if you have converted img to an inline shape then you can use `img.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = StyleName`

Comment: i did not realize how the style property changed based on the paragraph it is placed into. This is very useful information and will help me alot with my current project. Thanks again